# How to use express-react-views in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, express, view, reactjs, sails.js

I tried to impliment express-react-views in Sailsjs by setting `engine: 'jsx',` in `config/views.js`, but it returns the following error:

```
info: Starting app...

warn: [Function]
error: Invalid view engine (jsx)-- are you sure it supports `consolidate`?
error: Your configured server-side view engine (jsx) could not be found.
error: Usually, this just means you need to install a dependency.
error: To install jsx, run:  `npm install jsx --save`
error: Otherwise, please change your `engine` configuration in config/views.js.
/Users/henry/Documents/dev/node/project/server/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/configure.js:75
            throw e;
                  ^
Error
```

How should I properly use express-react-views in a Sails project?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [this Tutorial](https://medium.com/@larsbs/how-to-use-react-as-a-template-engine-in-sails-js-bb6b22c7dba6#.ggm1aihpb) you see that you have to set the engine to

```
engine: {
  ext: 'jsx',
  fn: require('express-react-views').createEngine()
}
```

after installing express-react-views, react and react-dom. For me the tutorial worked fine when setting the file extension of the view files to jsx.